# Weird Active Directory behavior after ADMT migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, replication, migration, dfs-r

We have multiple sites with multiple DC's. Since performing the migrations we have been experiencing all sorts of problems with DFSR etc.

We have multiple objects in the AD ..

> - DCNAME
> - DCNAMECNF:f9f56ebd-0883-4905-a82e-e152f3ba402c

anyone experienced this before?
we are contemplating demoting & disjoining ensuring ad object gets deleted then rejoining the domain and promoting to DC/GC

Answer (score 0):

When you introduce 2 AD objects with the same name, a naming conflict occurs, and the oldest object will be renamed by appending `CNF:<guid>`.

`CNF:` is probably short for "CoNFlict"

Comment: Dammit!! I'll check this in the morning.. thanks any how!